# Is $M$ unique given $A= M^2$ where $A$ and $M$ are real matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is $M$ unique given $A= M^2$ where $A$ and $M$ are real matrices?
My guessing is they are unique as I tried to diagonalize $A$ to $PDP^{-1}$ and no matter how I order the eigenvalues in $D$, it still gives the same $M = PD^{\frac{1}{2}}P^{-1}$. But I am not sure this is true in general, since the diagonalization is too specific.

Looking for some hints to prove it in general.

Comment: Please use MathJax *throughout* your post, not just in some places. Say $A$ is the identity. Then $M$ can be both $A$ and $-A$.

Comment: Good one! Thanks to both of you. 

Change has been made, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It is also not necessarily the case that there are only finitely many such matrices $M$. For example, if $A = I \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, then every matrix of the form
$$
M = \pmatrix{1 & t\\0 & -1}, \quad t \in \Bbb R
$$
satsifies $M^2 = A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if $M$ is any $n\times n$ matrix satisfying $A=M^2$ (we then say that $M$ is a square root of $A$) then $-M$ is also a square root of $A$. For this kind of problem it helps to first think about the case where $A$ and $M$ are scalars then think about whether or not the same argument holds for matrices.

Even if $A$ is diagonalizable (which doesn't always hold), your argument using diagonalization doesn't really work here since there are many choices for $D^{1/2}$ (Note that $D^{1/2}$ is by definition **any** matrix satisfying $D^{1/2}D^{1/2}=D$). For instance, in the special case where $A$ has $n$ distinct nonzero eigenvalues, there are $2^n$ choices for this matrix. Explicitly, if $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ then all square roots are of the form $\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$ where $\mu_i$ is any number (real or complex) satisfying $\mu_i^2=\lambda_i$ (there are exactly two of them for each $i$).

---

**Sidenote:** There is actually a way to assign a unique square root of $A$ satisfying a certain property in the special case that $A$ is positive semidefinite, called the principal square root. This can be done due to the following theorem:

> **Theorem:**  Let $A$ be a symmetric real positive semidefinite matrix. Then there is exactly one positive semidefinite matrix $B$ such that $A=B^2$.

Comment: Also, note that the non-semi-positive definite square root of matrices are NOT unique either(as the example @Ben Grossmann pointed out) even there's the fact that positive-definite one is, unlike in the integer set we have both positive and negative square roots uniquely.

Comment: like your explanation! very clear and thoughtful! @ projectilemotion.

good spot as well! @ Lab